# Server bash-ls starting exited with status exit

Tags: lsp-mode, bash

I keep seeing following error when I run `emacs daemon`.

```
Server bash-ls:7089/starting exited with status exit(check corresponding
stderr buffer for details). Do you want to restart it? (y or n)
```

When I press `y` the same message show up again.

my config file:

```
(define-derived-mode my-cfg-mode sh-mode "My CFg Mode"
  "A mode for my CFg files."
  (sh-set-shell "bash"))
```

=> How could I prevent this message to show up or respond it `n` by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the variable `lsp-restart`. According to the documentation, there are three choices: `interactive`, `auto-restart` and `ignore`. The default value is `interactive`, you can select `ignore`.

```
(with-eval-after-load "lsp-mode"
    (setq lsp-restart 'ignore))
```

However, [this page](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/faq/) indicates that the server may have crashed. Did you check the logs in the `*bash-ls::stderr*` buffer?